# Sitefinity 8.2 Filtering Back-end by Dynamic Module Items

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-8

I've tried asking this on the Sitefinity forums, but have had no responses over the past two weeks or so.

I have a custom dynamic module (built with the module builder), Projects. Each project object has a reference to another dynamic module, Vendors. In the back-end listing, I would like to add the ability to filter by one or more of these linked vendors. I'm envisioning something similar to the taxonomy filtering found here: http://screencast.com/t/xiLZNETLDM5v.

I've made some progress on this, but have hit a bit of a wall. I added a new sidebar filter to my modules Filter section, then, I added a new sidebar section for my filter.

My vendors section of my sidebar is configured with the Closevendors button as the vendorsFilter. For the vendorsFilter, I have no Data Source or Custom Commands configured, but the itemType is tied to my type.  The filter itself uses the DynamicModules  data.svc to serve the list of vendors. The ItemsCount is not populated, but, I'm not terribly concerned with that at the moment.

Up to this point, aside from the ItemCount missing (which, I understand, my service call is not contextualized to my module) I get my list of vendors correctly. However, when I click on a vendor, I get an error citing an embedded call in a script resource file (call stack: http://screencast.com/t/Uq3ipgcSv). I assume this is due to Sitefinity not having all the information it needs to filter my data. How can I provide this data so that my client can filter their data by related items?

If there is anything I'm missing, or anything that is unclear, please let me know.

I appreciate any assistance.

Thanks